# FMS server-side code not executing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm trying to create a RTMP Streaming application but I can't seem to get the server-side code to run. I've checked the logs on RootInstaller/logs/test, but nothing inside it.  I am running everything locally also.

Here's what I have:

ActionScript3 file

```
public function btnConnectHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/test");
}
```

fms.ini:

```
TEST_DIR = C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 4.5\applications\test
```

Main.acs

```
// Called when a client connects
application.onConnect = function(client) {
    // accept the new client's connection
    application.acceptConnection(client);

    // send a message
    trace(client.id + " is connected"); 
}
```

Also inside my `applications` folder I have the following files:

`allowedHTMLdomains.txt`

`Application.xml`

`main.acs`

Comment: Add a simple `trace` function (like `trace("onConnect is called")`) at the first line of the `onConnect` method. Does it log?

Comment: @EminA.Alekperov I see it logging now in the FMS log folder.  Last night I was playing with the file name of main.acs, I wonder if that is what was causing it not to write to the `rootinstaller/log`. Anyways, can you please copy your comment as an answer and I will check it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a simple `trace` function (like `trace("onConnect is called")`) at the first line of the `onConnect` method. Does it log?